# Catch Command Line Input, Exit If Input = x; Else Continue

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I have a CLI script that runs for days. It processes batches, each of which take around 7 minutes. Sometimes I need to stop the script, but I need to stop it only once a batch has been processed, which is a 2 second sleep I have put in. Is there any way I can catch input at any stage of the scripts execution, if that input = x, then stop the script at the end of the next batch; else continue.

I have come across:

```
$handle = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
$line = fgets($handle);
```

but this require input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you going to get it the way you are thinking. You can catch the `StdOut` but I don't think it will do you much good in terms of stopping the script. If I was using this on the cli and it ran all the time but I wanted to pause it for a certain amount of time you can do many things but this is probably how I would tackle it for a **"quick fix"**.

Restructure your php code a tiny bit and put the batching process inside a function if it's not already. Then you can create an infinite loop using `while`. Then I would have it check for the existence of a pause file after each batch process. If the file exists, then don't start the next batch. Basically pausing it. If it doesn't exist proceed on as normal.

So for example.

You php file could look like this little example.

```
<?php

//path to pause file
$filename = "/root/pause";

while(1){
 if(!file_exists($filename)){
   batch();
  }
}

function batch(){
 //batch processing
  echo "batching\n";
  //fake processing using a usleep pause
  usleep(3000000);
}

?>
```

Then when you want to pause the script. just create the file `pause` and when the current processing completes it will stop.

So to create the file on Linux, cd to the directory in the script and run the command

```
touch pause
```

or you can use the full path like `touch /path/to/pause`. Just make sure it's in the same directory as in your script. When you are done, just delete the file `rm -f pause` and it will resume processing the batches.

Note that when it's paused and it's just looping and not processing, it could cause a little jump in cpu usage, however it should be fine.

Long term you can look at this little example to get you going in that direction. 
http://www.phpmysqlitutorials.com/2013/05/08/php-standard-input-and-loops-on-the-command-line/

Comment: I've done something similar: created a web page that allows me to toggle a database variable, which is checked at the end of each batch.